# Booyer-Moore or similar in Java or Scala Libraries

Tags: java, algorithm, scala

I am looking for a simple API to return a list of all the indexes where a sequence alignment occurs between a small string and a larger string.

Is there any method in the java or Scala libraries that do this?

Comment: I don't see why this question deserved a down vote…

Comment: The [Z algorithm](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107) is very easy to code, fast, and solves this exact problem as a side effect

Comment: The algorithm is called **Boyer-Moore**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for kooking further. **indexOf** does the trick.
For one element:

```
"test" indexOf "es"
res4: Int = 1
```

For more elements:

```
scala> List("beer" , "root beer", "bavarian beer" , "a beer bong" ) map (_ indexOf "beer")
res6: List[Int] = List(0, 5, 9, 2)
```

If you want to use something else it would be best to stick to some standard implementations widely used.
For example *Apache Commons* http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/ has a good StringUtils package which contains string matching algorithms.

For Boyer-Moore there are myriads of implementations. On Wikipedia you even find a Java implementation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use IndexOf to find every element instead of just one? Do you know where I can find code for that? Secondly, do you know what algorithm index Of uses?